# Как правильно внедрить appodeal в ios приложение на swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Не мог найти уроков или туториалов по appodeal. В их инструкции на сайте не всё понятно. Например, вот этот пункт. Я так понял все эти фреймворки нужно добавить? (там их огромный список)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А ещё вот этот пункт: 8.2. Linker Flags: Click Project -> Build Settings -> Search for other linker flags -> Add "-ObjC". Я еле нашёл поле other linker flags и нажал под ним плюсик и добавил "-ObjC". Но я сомневаюсь так ли я сделал.

[image: правильно ли я добавил?]

Но больше всего непонятен этот пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут написано, что надо проинициализировать sdk в appdelegate следующими методами. Но далее показан код только из viewController, а как его инициализировать в appdelegate не показано.

И самый главный вопрос. Когда я запросил рекламу, и она загрузилась, срабатывает метод func nativeAdLoader(_ loader: APDNativeAdLoader!, didLoad nativeAd: APDNativeAd!). Но как мне отобразить эту рекламу? Например, у меня есть таблица с ячейками. В одних ячейках показываются обычные посты, а в некоторых нативная реклама. Так вот после срабатывания этого метода, как мне загрузить в ячейку полученную нативную рекламу?

Comment: правильно ли я понял, вы хотите чтоб кто то пошел и прочитал за вас документацию?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko нет, не правильно. Я прочитал документацию, но не нашёл там ответы на данные вопросы. Я лишь спрашиваю у людей, которые внедряли эту рекламу: 1. правильно ли я добавил ObjC, 2. как инициализировать в appDelegate, 3. как отобразить загруженную рекламу в каком-нибудь UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) да, вам надо добавить все библиотеки из списка.

2) нет, вы добавили `-ObjC` неправильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Вот, что я вижу в документации, возможно у вас страница не загрузилась вся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) Чтобы после получения от делегата информации, что реклама загрузилась, ее показать, вам надо создать вью. Опять же вот пример из документации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. У меня ещё вопрос. Я в классе своего вьюконтроллера импортировал апподил, добавил делегат APDNativeAdLoaderDelegate, а потом реализовал два метода, один из которых nativeAdLoader(loader: APDNativeAdLoader!, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error!), но xcode подчеркнул Error. Похоже что Error из swift 3, но если я подставляю NSError (у меня swift 2), то тогда ругается на то место где делегат добавил и пишет, что класс не удовлетворяет протоколу. Или лучше для этого создать отдельный вопрос на SO?

Comment: наверно лучше отдельный вопрос. надо покопаться

Comment: Вот тут создал вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628385/207604