# Как превратить NSError в Error в swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift

Возможно вопрос звучит странно. Но я использую делегат, который требует реализации метода, где одним из аргументов является Error (который является аналогом NSError в swift 3). Но моё приложение написано на swift 2.

Если точнее я пытаюсь внедрить appodeal и пока загвоздка только в том что метод для отслеживания неудачной попытки загрузки рекламы не работает.

```swift
    func nativeAdLoader(loader: APDNativeAdLoader!, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error!) {

    }
```

xCode подчёркивает Error и говорит, что такой тип не задекларирован. Пример метода я брал с сайта appodeal из документации. Если я подставляю вместо Error - NSError, то тогда делегат подчёркивается и пишет, что класс не соответствует протоколу. Оно логично, ведь протокол видимо требует чтобы там был Error.

Так вот меня интересует, можно ли как-то обмануть протокол или метод? Например, как-то задекларировать тип Error, чтобы он был NSError? Скорее всего я даже не буду пользоваться этим методом, мне всего лишь надо, чтобы он не подчёркивал ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что самым подходящим решением для Вас будет переписать Ваше приложение на Swift3. Смешивать 2 версии одного и того же языка в одном приложении крайне нежелательно. Насколько я знаю Appodeal не предоставляют исходные коды своего SDK для iOS. Поэтому воспользуйтесь встроенным в XCode конвертером кода и работайте только с языком Swift3 в Вашем проекте.

Comment: На самом деле проблема решилась иначе. Я копировал функцию из документации, а надо было просто начать писать название функции и из предложенных вариантов выбрать нужный. И тогда всё работает и на swift2. Правда теперь это уже не актуально, так как во-первых отказались от апподил, а во-вторых проект и так пришлось перевести на свифт 3.